# ENS with Smart Contract

Tags: testnets, ens

Is it possible to assign a name with Ethereum Name Service to a Smart Contract's address on a testnet? I found a description only for personal wallet.

Answer (score 1):

It works the same both ways. Assigning an ENS name is just linking the name to an address. That address could be a contract, your wallet, or just a random address.